# Using Cloudflare with S3 Website

Tags: amazon-s3, cloudflare

I have configured and running static website with S3, before this website was running with `Beanstalk` as Nodejs application and CloudFlare, so, I decided to serve it with S3 as Webserver, the website is up and running on S3.

Example :

```
http://example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/
```

The domain in CloudFlare is already activated and I created the `CNAME record` pointing to `example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com`, it should work, but it doesn't.

If I add the `AWS's Name Servers configured with HostedZones in Router53` in Godaddy, when I access `example.com` it works.

the name servers look likes

```
ns-XXX.awsdns-38.org. 
ns-XX.awsdns-12.com. 
ns-XXX.awsdns-15.net. 
ns-XXX.awsdns-56.co.uk.
```

If I add these NS's in Cloudflare the `example.com` doesn't work, I'd like to use CloudFlare and host thr website with S3.

If I add the NS's in Godaddy, it works.

If I add the NS's in CloudFlare, it doesn't works.

What's wrong?

Comment: If you are using Cloudflare, you can't also be using a Route 53 hosted zone, and you shouldn't be creating a CNAME record pointing directly to the bucket -- that would prevent the requests from actually passing through Cloudflare en route to the bucket... and that is what you are trying to do, isn't it?  You also should have the Cloudflare name servers configured with Go Daddy (assuming that is your domain's registrar).  You are wanting to use Cloudflare as a cache in front of your bucket-hosted web site... right?

Comment: ```"You are wanting to use Cloudflare as a cache in front of your bucket-hosted web site... right?"``` YES! and use the CloudFlare SSL, pointing to AppEngine it worked, but the S3 bucket didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

See the following - and note the section on "Using SSL with AWS S3 and Cloudflare" (http may work OK, but https may not respond)
https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168926-How-do-I-use-Cloudflare-with-Amazon-s-S3-Service-

... and also see the S3 doc on CNAME flattening
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html#VirtualHostingCustomURLs

ps. Michael's comment re Route53 is correct - there's no hosted zone setup required as described in quick start examples such as https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html